# Play a video from Youtube in a AVPlayerViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, avplayerviewcontroller

Okay so I'm looking to play film trailers in my app. The user will press a button, and then it plays the video. I have added the `import AVKit` and `import AVFoundation` lines to my file. This is the code I have so far for making the video play:

```
@IBAction func playTrailerPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://youtu.be/d88APYIGkjk")
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {

        playerViewController.player!.play()

    }

}
```

This seems to launch an `AVPlayerViewController`, but doesn't play the video from YouTube. Instead, I get the below:

[image]

I have tried both the sharing and embedding link from YouTube, but neither work. If I use a link which has the video file name at the end, it plays it fine, for example: `"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"`- So I know the code works.

Does anyone know if this is possible to use this way with a YouTube video? (I have also tried trailers from IMDb and Apple, but it's the same).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use instead UIWebView

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`AVPlayer` only plays movie files, and YouTube videos aren't directly exposed as movie files at their URL. It looks like the preferred way to handle YouTube videos is to embed a web view into your app. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) for information from Google on how to do that.