# Can't play video using AvPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

I want to play video from Server through following code using swift 3 in tableview cell.When i play video from bundle then play successfully.But from server can't play.How i can play?

```
let url = URL(string: "http://68d07921.ngrok.io/modules/users/client/videos/video.mp4")
    avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
    avpController.player = AVPlayer.init(url: url!)
    avpController.view.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
    avpController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(avpController.view)
    self.videoPlayerView.autoresizesSubviews = true
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to play the video from that link in your browser? I have. It won't open.

Comment: yes it is playing.

Comment: if i use another link from youtube then  same error.

Comment: i also used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRpeEdMmmQ0 this link

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34709948

Comment: @paiv but i don't want to play youtube video.

Comment: YouTube link isn't a video.

Comment: @ Max http://68d07921.ngrok.io/modules/users/client/videos/video.mp4 this is my url link.

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram you player probably fails on timeout. I waited more than 2 minutes, and it still didn't start playing.