# How can i play / stream youtube video in MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mwphotobrowser

i want to stream youtube videos in [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) in my iOS app, i searched a lot for this but did not got any success as [same issue](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/issues/488). If anyone have used or using this library please help.

Comment: It's not supported out of the box, you will have to build it yourself.

Comment: I dont think, avplayer would be able to play youtude video because youtube video urls are not .mp4 or in any similar format but are embedded links. follow the link [Play a video from Youtube in a AVPlayerViewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709880/play-a-video-from-youtube-in-a-avplayerviewcontroller-in-swift) for better understanding.

Comment: Rckoenes and Pawan thanks for quick respond! as MWPhotoBrowser not supports this functionality, i'm now using @pawan's suggestion for this :)